# Compatibility chart

Tags: wifi, bluetooth, audio, asus

I am planning to move to Elementary OS and was wondering if there is a kind of compatibility chart. I'm planning to buy an ASUS UX390UA, but I would like to have everything working properly. Like sound, Wifi, bluetooth, keyboard, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an Ubuntu hardware compatibility list (https://certification.ubuntu.com/desktop/) though no Asus machines are in the list. That doesn't mean they aren't compatible by any means. It just means they haven't been tested by Ubuntu (elementary OS's base).

Personally I've seen Dell machines work best with linux. I've never had any compatibility issues.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was looking at the ASUS because it's fairly powerful and extremely lightweight. I'm using a 12" MacBook now but many times the video card and Core M processor are not enough. The ASUS Zenbook 3 is the closest match, with a decent processor (i5 or i7) and a 512SSD. So I guess I'll have to take the plunge and send it back it I can't make it work.

Comment: You t want to look at the Lenovo yoga.. I think it'll get you what you're looking for plus it's on the official Ubuntu supported hardware lisr

Answer (score 1):

I did some digging for you, and couldn't find anything in the official Ubuntu Hardware Compatibility list. However, I own an Asus E403S which works fine with elementary OS - I know it's older than the one you're looking at, but it's similar.

Also, there is an Ubuntu Forums post [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2340639) that shows that there are at least a few minor issues surrounding that particular laptop. Asus makes nice laptops, and the hardware is fairly standard, so I say go for it.

Comment: Thanks, Ben. I can live without the fingerprint scanner, but there doesn't seem to be a solution for the sound issue, which will bother me. I'll do some more research to see if I can find a solution or maybe another machine that's better suited.

Comment: Not a problem. As far as I know, the sound works fine on my Asus laptop, but I generally have it muted all the time. I don't really watch videos or listen to music on my laptop...that's what my phones for, but I can easily see that as a deal breaker. Best of luck to you on your hunt!

Comment: You are right there. I rarely use the speakers of my MacBook right now, so maybe it's not that important after all.